# Nginx: cannot load certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl

```
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/domain.io.chain.pem": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:Type=X509 error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib)
```

I get this cryptic error that I can't find any info on.

```
openssl verify domain.io.chain.pem
domain.io.chain.pem: OK
```

I've done all I can to ensure it's not about permissions, like setenforce 0, move the files to /etc/nginx/ssl, use 0644 mode on them and ensure the parent dir has 0755, also tried setting nginx user as group owner, ensured workers run as nginx user, that nginx user is member of nginx group and that nginx was completely shutdown to end all user sessions after running useradd.

Also ensured I'm not setting anything like ssl_protocols or ssl_ciphers in the nginx configuration.

The .pem file is three certs all put together that I got from the CA. First two are intermediate CA certs and the 3rd is the "web server cert".

If I move the web server cert first openssl verify fails. But changing order of the two intermediate certs does nothing to openssl verify results.

I've also tried removing the two intermediate certs just to see if nginx would accept it.

Here is the full nginx config for that vhost. The rest is a vanilla CentOS 7 install of nginx 1.16.1.

```
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name domain.io;

  proxy_connect_timeout  120s;
  proxy_send_timeout     120s;
  proxy_read_timeout     120s;
  send_timeout           120s;

  proxy_buffer_size   4k;
  proxy_buffers   8 4k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size  8k; # Must always be proxy_buffer_size*2
  #proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
  client_max_body_size 1024M;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location @backend {
    client_max_body_size 1024m;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://staging_backend;

  }

  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.io-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.io-error.log notice;

}

# TLS
server {

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name domain.io;

  ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/domain.io.chain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/domain.io.key;

  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;
  #ssl_stapling on;
  #ssl_stapling_verify on;

  #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  #ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";

  proxy_connect_timeout  120s;
  proxy_send_timeout     120s;
  proxy_read_timeout     120s;
  send_timeout           120s;

  proxy_buffer_size   4k;
  proxy_buffers   8 4k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size  8k; # Must always be proxy_buffer_size*2
  #proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
  client_max_body_size 1024M;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location @backend {
    client_max_body_size 1024m;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://staging_backend;

  }

  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.io-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.io-error.log notice;

}
```

Comment: You should order the certificates from _leaf_ to _root_, i.e. your certificate comes first, then its signer, the signer's signer, etc. (cf. [ssl_certificate directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate))

Comment: Ok I don't know what is wrong. I received one cert called "web server cert", and two called "intermediate CA certs". If I place the web server one first openssl verify fails with a similar error to nginx. But nginx still fails with the same error. openssl verify only works with the reverse order. I've also checked the CAs public cert repo and tried a bunch of their intermediate and root certs but none match to the ones I was given. I guess I'll have to ask the issuer for help.

Comment: Save every certificate in a separate file and use `openssl x509 -in <certificate_file> -noout -subject -issuer` to decrypt which certificate is which. Afterwards concatenate them starting from your certificate, then it's issuer, then the issuer's issuer, etc.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Ok that is very clear to me, thanks. So what if the "leaf" says an error and the others don't? The "web server cert" I got from the issuer is the only one unable to be loaded into openssl x509. All the others I have identified and found on the Issuers public facing website of root and intermediate certs.

Comment: Open the file with a text editor. If it is in `PEM` format, it has a couple of lines of comments followed by `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I can verify that something was wrong with the leaf cert from the issuer. They sent me a new file in PFX format. I then exported the leaf cert from it and the formatting was clearly different from the initial file I received. Now it works. Thakns for all your help but I guess this question has no real answer. If you want you can post one and I'll mark it for points. ;)